# New ConnectAPI.PollCapabilityInput() Compile Fail

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, connect-api

```
​ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput();
```

The above code does not compile. The error says:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: ConnectApi.​PollCapabilityInput

Other ConnectApi uses are fine. The class is at API version 34.0. Any one has the same issue?

Comment: What is your API version of the class? Check in the .xml

Comment: API version is 34.0

Comment: How are you saving the file  Eclipse, MavensMate or directly in Browser?

Comment: Directly in Browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the namespace `ConnectApi`:

`ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput();`

seems to be working for me.

**Execute Anonymous via Developer Console (browser):**

```
ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput();
pollInput.choices = new List <String> {'Option 1'};
system.debug(pollInput.choices[0]);
```

**Result:**

> 09:55:19:078 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|Option 1

Comment: That was a typo. I have ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput pollInput = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput(); I couldn't save this in browser. Other calls are working.

Comment: can you please attach your example method here?

Comment: Updated my answer @user4402671

Comment: Thank you so much!! I copied them into developer console and there was a bad character. Now I got this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing connectApi. If not then this issue generally comes when we save apex class from eclipse or some other IDE, In your case you should have 34.0 version of force.com plugin ID.Try to save in Browser.It should work